# Segmentation fault while trying to make 2x2 grid

Tags: c, gcc, c99

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void initialization(int n, int grid[n][n]){
  srand(time(0));
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    int no1 = 0, no0 = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
      int checker = rand();
      if(no1 != n/2 && no0 != n/2){
        if(checker % 2 == 0){
          grid[i][j]=1;
          no1++;
        }
        else{
          grid[i][j]=0;
          no0++;
        }
      }
      else if(no1 != n/2 && no0 == n/2){
        grid[i][j]=1;
        no1++;
      }
      else if(no1 == n/2 && no0 != n/2){
        grid[i][j]=0;
        no0++;
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
      printf("%d", grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter an even number between [2,80]: ");
  scanf("%d",n);
  if(n % 2 == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  
  int grid[n][n];
  
  initialization(n, &grid);
  return 0;
}
```

So this is what im trying to do: Im trying to ask the user to enter an even value and then make an nxn grid. This nxn grid is supposed to have random number of n/2 1's and 0's in each row. But for some reason every time i run this code i get a segmentation error

Comment: in *main* replace `scanf("%d",n);`by `scanf("%d",&n);` and `initialization(n, &grid);`  by `initialization(n, grid);` => vote to close for 'typo'

Comment: the second problem is signaled by *gcc* even without option, the two problems are signaled by *gcc* using the option `-Wall` I encourage you to always use that option and **to take into account the warnings** whose are a great help to correct your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `scanf("%d",n);` invoked *undefined behavior* for passing data having wrong type and using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate. Add `&` like `scanf("%d",&n);` to pass *a pointer to* `n`.
- The second argument of `initialization(n, &grid);` have wrong type. Remove the `&` to pass `grid`, which will be converted to `int(*)[2]`.

Your `main` function should be:

```
int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter an even number between [2,80]: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  if(n % 2 == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  
  int grid[n][n];
  
  initialization(n, grid);
  return 0;
}
```

Also checking the return value of `scanf()` to check if it is successful like this will improve your code more:

```
int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter an even number between [2,80]: ");
  if(scanf("%d",&n) != 1){
    fputs("read error\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  if(n % 2 == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  
  int grid[n][n];
  
  initialization(n, grid);
  return 0;
}
```